# Caption when posting to Instagram not working

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram

When posting photos to Instagram, no caption is shown, it's just empty.

Has Instagram disabled this feature? 
If not it is possible that my code is incorrect.

Here's how I tried doing it:

```
-(void)shareImageOnInstagram:(UIImage *)image
{
    //Must be 612x612
    NSString* imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/instagramShare.igo", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];

    UIImage *instagramImage = image;
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(instagramImage) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Image Size >>> %@", NSStringFromCGSize(instagramImage.size));

    self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"mmm" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

    self.docController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
    self.docController.delegate = self;
    self.docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES ];
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've initialized the `UIDocumentInteractionController` after attempting to set the annotation.  You have to switch those two lines around, like so:

```
self.docController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];

self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Posted using #Truthly" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
self.docController.delegate = self;
self.docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
[self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES ];
```